# Что сделать чтобы в конструкторе не было много параметров

Tags: java

Всем привет! Есть такой конструктор который считывает информацию о квартире:

```
public Flat(Address flatAddress, double flatArea, boolean furnishing, int bedroomsNum, double flatPrice, List<InfrastructureObject> infrustructure)
```

Также есть конструкторы Адреса:

```
public Address(String country,String town,String street,int houseNumber)
```

И конструктор инфраструктуры:

```
 public InfrastructureObject(InfrastructuresType infrastructuresType,String infrastructureObjectName,double distance)
```

в итоге , когда я создаю квартиру(объект) получается огромный конструктор вроде этого:

```
Flat flat1 = new Flat(new Address("Great Britain", "London", "Linkoln St.", 25), 290,
                true, 4, 750, new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new InfrastructureObject(InfrastructuresType.SCHOOL, "School №19", 900),
                new InfrastructureObject(InfrastructuresType.HYPERMARKET, "Victoria Gardens hypermarket", 800))));
```

Как можно сократить такой конструктор, дабы он занимал меньше места по скольку в будущем мне надо будет создавать список квартир? Спасибо за предложения!!!

Comment: Все параметры в конструкторе обязательны ? И эти данные должны быть уже инициализированы при создании объекта ?

Comment: Для сокращения прототипа, можно использовать передачу коллекции. Иначе это сделать нельзя.

Comment: Если какой либо из ответов помог вам, то примите его и поставьте плюс, нажав на галочку и стрелку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 3):

В зависимости от того объект у вас должен ли быть неизменяемый и все ли параметры должны быть проиницилизированны.

1. Можно сделать конструктор без параметров и использовать set-ры

   - ваш объект будет изменяемы - что не всегда хорошо
2. Можно применить [билдер паттерн](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)
3. Для списков можно использовать add методы

   - например для Flat можно добавить метод что-то типа 
     `addInfrastructureObject(InfrastructureObject infrustructure)`

Comment: Нет, объект квартиры должен быть неизмяем и определен на стадии пре-компиляции, по сколько в рантайме мы должны будем указывать парметры по которым будет определятся список рекоммендованных квартир.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, хардкодить конкретные названия прямо в Java - это значит самому себе проблемы в будущем создать. Надо объекты создавать из БД - ну на крайний случай с текстового файла. Тогда и код будет выглядеть более компактным автоматически.

Во-вторых, InfrastructuresType.SCHOOL - не очень хорошее решение с позиции ООП - потому что в методах Вам тогда придется писать "если тип такой-то то делай это, иначе если тип такой-то ..." - во что потом превращаются такие методы видел неоднократно. Намного лучше и короче просто new School(), причем в нем не надо будет тип проверять - у каждого объекта свой переопределенный метод.

В-третьих, new LinkedList<> - это тоже не очень хорошо. Например, есть документ, а есть журнал документов - это разные сущности со своим поведением и свойствами. Думаю то же самое есть и в Вашем случае.

Если хотя бы эти три рекомендации используете - код значительно сократится и будет намного более читаемым.

Comment: В данном случае речь идёт о простом консольном приложении и насчёт типов инфраструктуры всё так и задумывалось по скольку недвижимость также будет харатеризоваться расстояние до определённных объектов социальной инфраструктуры.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить использовать паттерн [`Fluent Interface`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java). Он похож на `Builder`. Суть такова - в классе, для которого у вас пишется такой большой конструктор, вы должны объявить пустой публичный конструктор по умолчанию + `set` методы для каждой переменной, которые возвращают `this`. Пример:

```
class ClassA {
  ...
  public ClassA setVar1(... var1) {
    this.var1 = var1;
    return this;
  }
  ...
}
```

В итоге, при создании объекта вам нужно будет сделать так:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA()
             .setVar1(...)
             .setVar2(...)
             .setVar3(...);
```

Comment: А теперь представьте на сколько раздуется код внутри метода, если будет 100+ объектов.

Comment: @And внутри какого метода? Там не один метод, и ничего в методах не раздуется из-за присутствия объектов. Да, количество методов увеличиться. Но я не говорю, что стоит отказываться от его предыдущей формы.

Comment: Как вы узнаете какой объект или тип прилетел, без его жесткой проверки через классификацию или инстанс, к тому-же вы, не укоротили прототип, он по прежнему будет множественной передачей, через запятую. Самым верным решением будет коллекция, она может быть собрана по разному и унаследованна также с множественной передачей данных, а прилетит только лишь одна, лишь разбор будет разным, если это потребуется.

Comment: @And про что вы говорите? Вы знакомы с паттерном Fluent Interface? И что за прототип? Если вы говорите про конструктор - то я предполагаю, что там будет 2 вида конструктора - пустой публичный(как в коде выше) и публичный конструктор как у автора(чтобы при желании он мог использовать свой вариант).

Comment: Пф... Там где перечисляются аргументы. Зачем лепить велик, когда есть для  этого коллекция, решающая задачу ТС'а моментально одной коллекцией и уже имеющей функцией добавки разных объектов. Причем за место тучи методов и классов, можно сделать всего один и юзать коллекцию, причем там и сортировки есть и все, все, все, нежели вы будете лепить велик.

Comment: @And https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUBRX.png
 У меня нет слов. Коллекции нужны совсем для другого, а у автора как раз пример для проработки ООП.

Comment: Шта?! Коллекции нужны для формирования данных, чтобы ими легче было оперировать, ТС, прямо сказал, сократить, а вы ему раздули методами. Гениально!

Comment: @And во первых, как автор будет помещать разные элементы в коллекцию? Точнее, он сможет это сделать(<Object>), но тогда у него вообще не будет преимущества от хранения этих объектов. Во вторых, логично хранить данные в полях, а  не смешанно в коллекции. В третьих, это не разгрузит ТС, потому что методов для добавления объектов в коллекцию будет столько же